# How to do a query on parse with a subclass of ParseUser?

Tags: android, parse-platform

On an Android application which used Parse, I would like to subclass ParseUser. I created my subclass User like this :

```
@ParseClassName("_User")
public class User extends ParseObject  {
    public User(){}

    public String getDisplayName() {   return getString("username");}
    public void setDisplayName(String value) {   put("username", value);}

    public String getFirstName(){return getString("firstname");}
    public void setFirstName(String value){put("firstname",value); }

   public String getObjectId()  {return getObjectId();}

   public String getFacebookId(){return getString("facebookId");}

   public ParseFile getProfilePictureSmall(){return getParseFile("profilePictureSmall");}
   public void setProfilePictureSmall(ParseFile file) {put("profilePictureSmall",file);}
   public Boolean getPlaceCaptured(){return getBoolean("placeCaptured");}
   public void setPlaceCaptured(Boolean value){put("placeCaptured",value);}

   public String getProfileDesc(){return getString("profileDesc");}
   public void setProfileDesc(String value){put("profileDesc",value);}

   public Date getCreatedAt(){return getDate("createdAt");}
   public void setCreatedAt(Date date){put("createdAt",date);}

   public Date getUpdatedAt(){return getDate("updatedAt");}
   public void setUpdatedAt(Date date){put("updatedAt",date);}
}
```

Then in Parseapplication I put :

```
 ParseObject.registerSubclass(User.class);
 Parse.initialize(this, "xxxx", "xxxx");
```

Everything goes right but When I try to Query a list of user like this :

```
  userQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<User>() {
        public void done(List<User> object, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null && object!=null && !object.isEmpty()) {


                for(User item : object)
                {
                    if(item!=null) {
                        User userReference = ParseObject.createWithoutData(User.class, item.getObjectId());
                        mUser.add(userReference);
                        mCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



                        Log.i("My Parse User = ", item.getDisplayName());
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Log.i("DONE","FAILED");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

in object I get a list of ParseUser (and not User) Is it normal ? My cast at this line doesn't work :

```
    for(User item : object)
```

Do I need  all the getter/setter on my subclass to be the EXACTLY the same as the ParseUser table ?
Can I have just 2 or 3 getter/ setter on my subclass versus 10 columns on my ParseUser class ?
Is it possible to subclass and query a ParseUser ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Ok my mistake... I extended the wrong class:

the right extension is :

```
   public class User extends ParseUser {
```

Comment: in my case forgot to add underscore at beginning